# ASP.NET Core 6 app not able to find UseWindowsService

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

My objective is to run an ASP.NET Core 6 app as Windows service in the simplest way, which I understood to use the code shown below.

I have included both of these lines (though only the top should be necessary):

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices;
```

and installed the nuget packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices" Version="6.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices" Version="6.0.0" />
```

But this code cannot resolve `.UseWindowsService()` when using `IWebHostBuilder`:

```
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseConfiguration(Configuration)
            .ConfigureServices(ConfigureServices)
            .UseUrls(Configuration.GetBindHostUrl())
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseWindowsService();   // not found
```

The error I get is:

> 'IWebHostBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseWindowsService' and the best extension method overload 'WindowsServiceLifetimeHostBuilderExtensions.UseWindowsService(IHostBuilder)' requires a receiver of type 'IHostBuilder'

What am I missing here?

Comment: Just to make it clear: You installed the .nuget for the extension?

Comment: @TheTanic yes - see update to question for even more clarity.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using the WebHost, you could try to use the more generic [IHostBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0):

```
 var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseWindowsService()
                .UseSystemd()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webbuilder =>
                {
                    //Configure here your WebHost. For example Startup;
                    webbuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

**Edit:**
Moved from the comments, because multiple people found it useful and to improve the visibility of the comment: 
To use the `UseWindowsService()` method, you need to install the [WindowsServices NuGet-Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices). In some cases, it will build without the NuGet-Package, but it will fail to run!

Comment: I just migrated a .net 5 project (VS2019) to .net 6 (VS2022). It sets up the host builder as above. In VS2022 / .net 6 it complains of error CS1061 'IHostBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseWindowsService' and yet it builds and runs OK (although I've not tried installing it as a service again yet). Puzzled.

Comment: Don't know why it still builds, but to use the `UseWindowsService()` method, you need to install the [NuGet-Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices)

Answer (score 6):

I just migrated from .net 3 to latest 7.0 and VS2019 to 2022, then had to install dependecies from NuGet Package Manager:

[image: nuget aditional extensions]

Then I was able to run on any Windows or Linux version.

For reference, to create a Windows Service just need a batch to run as administrator:

**Install.cmd**

```
chcp 1252>NUL
SET mypath=%~dp0

sc create "service.name" displayname= "display.name" binpath= %mypath:~0,-1%\app-name.exe start= auto
sc description "service.name" "service description"

NET START service.name

pause
```

**Uninstall.cmd**

```
NET STOP service.name
sc delete "service.name"
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices is for IHostBuilder, which is what new 3.0 apps use now.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices is for IWebHostBuilder.

You have to refer this Nuget package(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices) and use following code.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsService();

        }
        
        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseContentRoot(Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName))
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseKestrel((context, serverOptions) =>
                {
                    serverOptions.ListenAnyIP(1000);
                    serverOptions.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.5);
                });
```

Refer below link: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/16804